# How to get the library module's version from inside the module's code at runtime

Tags: android-library, android-package-managers, version-numbering

Having a Android library module, its version is defined in the build.gradle

```
group = 'com.sample.data'
version = 1.0.1
project.ext.artifactId = 'data_module'

apply plugin: 'com.android.library'
```

Inside its code when do log or reporting the crash it needs to include itself's version  (the 1.0.1).

using

```
val pInfo = context.getPackageManager()
                  .getPackageInfo(dataConfiguration.context.getPackageName(), 0)
val version = pInfo.versionName
```

only gets the hosting app's package info, not the library module's

How to get the library module's version from inside the module's code at runtime?

some post suggest to use the BuildConfig.VERSION_NAME,  but in the library module's code it cannt not be resolved (the list does not have the library itself)

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After adding same extra stuff in build.gradle's

```
defaultConfig {

}
```

in the code the `BuildConfig.VERSION_NAME` is resolved.

It can get the version from `BuildConfig.VERSION_NAME`.